# Compare a numeric value inside a string in Freemarker

Tags: string, integer, compare, freemarker

I have a use case wherein I get an amount in the form of a string and I need to compare it to an integer value. The string has the following conditions:
 1. Its first three letters denote the currency
 2. The string can consist of commas
For e.g. EUR 540,000 denotes 540000 Euros.

One way I can think of doing this is to:

1 Take a substring from the 4rth character using `?substring`

2 Eliminate the commas using `?replace`

3 Convert to a integer using `?number`

4 and then compare

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate that into a `#function` or a `TemplateMethodModelEx`. But really, the data-model (template context) you are using is rather strange. Especially if the template is supposed to do math, you should get the numbers (like `BigDecimal`-s or `Integer`-s), not those strings. So I would try to clean up the data-model before passing it to the template. That's the clean solution.